# Bluemix app stopped working with heroku-buildpack-multi - openssl.so.0.9.8 can't be found

Tags: ibm-cloud

App was working fine -- then today noticed it was not running. Looking at the logs I found this error:

```
  OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.0.2
2015-10-23T11:06:18.22-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        NOTICE: Your composer.json is completely empty.
2015-10-23T11:06:18.23-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Consider putting at least "{\"repositories\":[{\"packagist\":false}]}" in there to make it valid JSON.
2015-10-23T11:06:18.25-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php
2015-10-23T11:06:18.62-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Setting up runtime environment...
2015-10-23T11:06:18.64-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        - PHP 5.5.12
2015-10-23T11:06:44.17-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        - Apache 2.4.9
2015-10-23T11:06:48.43-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        - Nginx 1.4.6
2015-10-23T11:06:49.33-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing PHP extensions:
2015-10-23T11:06:49.39-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        - opcache (automatic; bundled, using 'ext-opcache.ini')
2015-10-23T11:06:49.46-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing dependencies...
2015-10-23T11:06:55.63-0400 [STG/0]      ERR php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2015-10-23T11:06:55.67-0400 [STG/0]      OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
2015-10-23T11:06:56.50-0400 [API/0]      ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

I have tried now 2 different heroku-buildpack-multi .. and both give the same error.

My manifest file looks like:

```
# buildpack: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
buildpack: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
domain: mybluemix.net
timeout: 80
services:
- licensedb
env:
  env_type: production
applications:
- name: GSLicense
  host: gxs-license
  path: ./htdocs
```

Any help would be appreciated as the application for my users is now down. :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually, due to Bluemix stack upgrade to cflinuxfs2, that buildpack has some problems.
A good solution could be to use the following one
https://github.com/zendtech/zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix already supporting this new stack
or the cf standard one
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue :(

I understand that bluemix in undergoing an upgrade to a new stack derived from Ubuntu 14.04.

Around September 30 You may have received a mail with instructions to self-migrate to the new stack, simply complete a one-time re-push of your app with your cf CLI command modified to add “-s cflinuxfs2”, for example:

> cf push your-app -s cflinuxfs2

From question 33295332 I understand that there were some issues around buildpacks. In case you receive an error like "App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase" see topic 33295332. I understand there are also buildpack updates scheduled.

Comment: The new stack does not seem to work well with the PHP heroku-buildpack, unregarding whether you are using Mysql or not. Simply updating the buildpack in my manifest.yml to https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack did the trick. Many thanks to @sjmcdowall for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out with a bit of help (and a lot of googling!).  First, it does have everything to do with the upgrade of the stack -- which alas did break PHP for me.  Here is how I solved it:
-- Used this multi build pack (I need php and java) in my manifest.yml

```
buildpack: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

Then I had to upgrade the PHP build pack in my .buildpacks under the root doc:

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
```

THEN -- since I am using mysqli, I had to add a

```
.bp-config/options.json
```

file under the doc root that contains the following:

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "bz2", "zlib", "curl", "mcrypt", "mysqli"]
}
```

Phew! Hope this helps.